# What's the relationship between NSAppearance, NSEffectView.Material, and "Vibrancy"

Tags: cocoa, appkit, nsvisualeffectview

As in the question title, what's the relationship between `NSAppearance`, `NSEffectView.Material`, and "vibrancy"? I've found through experimentation that, for some materials, the choice of `NSAppearance` can change how the material appears (e.g. `NSEffectView.Material.titlebar` will be light or dark depending on the active `NSAppearance`), while other materials (e.g. `.light`) don't seem to care.

I suspect that materials like `.titlebar` are proxies which select from `.dark`, `.ultradark`, `.light`, and `.mediumLight` depending on the `NSAppearance`, but then that would seem to be the role of `.appearanceBased`. I also see in the description for `NSAppearance.Name.vibrantLight`...

> This should only be set on an NSVisualEffectView or one of its subviews.

...which somewhat contradicts a statement from the `NSEffectView` documentation...

> The view’s effective appearance must allow vibrancy... in most cases you set the appearance on the window or on the visual effect view—subviews then inherit the appearance.

...suggesting that it could be correct to set `vibrantLight` as the `NSAppearance` of an entire window (if that's the look you wanted).

Finally, I'm confused as to what exactly "vibrancy" is; if someone could explain it, that would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So an [NSAppearance](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsappearance) generally describes the styling of controls, colors, etc for a view hierarchy that the appearance is set against.

NSVisualEffectView provides a way to achieve two effects: translucency and vibrancy. The former is the more obvious, with the translucent sidebars or titlebars. And the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsvisualeffectview) has a really nice description of vibrancy:

> Vibrancy is associated with translucency. It describes a compositing mode that does special blending such as Plus Lighter, Plus Darker, Color Dodge, or Color Burn.

Basically describing how the *content* (text, images, etc) within the visual effect view are composited against the translucency.

---

So how do these all relate?

#### Material

Material describes the look of the translucency effect. As you pointed out, some are affected by NSAppearance, some are not. The ones that are semantically describe their usage so that custom UI can resemble that effect regardless of appearance (`.appearanceBased`, `.titlebar`, `.menu`, `.popover`, `.sidebar`, `.selection`) whereas others allow for specific control over the resulting translucency (`.light`, `.dark`, `.mediumLight`, `.ultraDark`) but should be used in conjunction with their associated NSAppearance so that the content within the visual effect view can match the translucency effect. Unless you need specific control over the material, using appearance-sensitive / semantic ones can result for more standard UI.

#### Vibrancy

So in order to get the content vibrancy effects that NSVisualEffectView can provide, it needs to be used in conjunction with a vibrant appearance: `.vibrantLight` or `.vibrantDark`. Without setting a "vibrant" appearance, NSVisualEffectView will only provide the translucency effect in the background, and the content within it will look plain and not have the special blending modes like you see in sidebars or titlebars.

Comment: >> NSVisualEffectView provides a way to achieve 
>> two effects: translucency and vibrancy
    
Not true. It also does gaussian blurring with some materials (e.g. toolTip, hudWindow), and that is the main reason that people use it.